# Cannot get OpenGL to install

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, opengl

When I try to run an example application it says I am missing 
a file that is found in OpenGL.
I found information online and tried to install OpenGL with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libgl-dev
                 Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.2-0ubuntu3) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
                    Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev
 mesa-common-dev : Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdrm-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: I would suggest "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get upgrade" Do you see any errors? if you receive a reply similar to "run sudo dpkg --configure" etc - then run the command as suggested and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

And add the linker for the case of newer versions of Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```

Comment: What is this? sudo apt-get install binutils-gold I dont see it in my repos